# unused arguments in getPortfolio when using R

Tags: r, portfolio

I'm a beginner with R, and I'm trying to follow the code I found online to create an optimal portfolio. link to the page im following: http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfoliofunctions.pdf .when I get to the part with getPortfolio and I specify the arguments, I get an error message about unused arguments-what am I doing wrong? Below is the code im following up to the part where I get stuck -it says the arguments specified in the getPortfolio function are unused?

```
> asset.names <- c("MSFT", "NORD", "SBUX")
> er <- c(0.0427, 0.0015, 0.0285)
> names(er) <- asset.names
> covmat <- matrix(c(0.0
100, 0.0018, 0.0011,
+    0.0018, 0.0109, 0.0026,
+    0.0011, 0.0026, 0.0199),
+  nrow=3, ncol=3)
> rk.free <- 0.005
> dimnames(covmat)<- list(asset.names, asset.names)
> ew = rep(1,3)/3
> equalWeight.portfolio = getPortfolio(er=er,cov.mat=covmat,weights=ew)
```

and the error message:

```
Error in getPortfolio(er = er, cov.mat = covmat, weights = ew) : 
  unused arguments (er = er, cov.mat = covmat, weights = ew)
```

Comment: Can you check the definition of `getPortfolio`? In particulars, its arguments you can identify with: `formals("getPortfolio")`

Comment: Thank you so much for editing and helping, Eric. I used the formals("getPortolio") and the R output is simply : $object?

Comment: That means the `getPortfolio` you are tryin g to use is not the same than the one detailed in the documentation you shared. You should browse the content of the mentioned file `portfolio.r` to check its definition.  Maye you have a package loaded with a function having same name? Did you source all the content of the `.r` file? (you can find it here: http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolio.r)

Comment: Ok, that seemed to work, but now I get a new error message:

 Error in chol.default(cov.mat) : 
  the leading minor of order 3 is not positive definite

Im pretty sure my covariance matrix is correct so Im not sure what the error could be now? I promise this is my last question in this topic :) ill crack my brains if additional ones come up later on.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you again Eric for all your help :)

Answer (score 2):

### need to first install and load the IntroCompFinR package the codes below will help

`install.packages("IntroCompFinR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

`library("IntroCompFinR")`

### then you can run the code

`asset.names <- c("MSFT", "NORD", "SBUX")`

```
er <- c(0.0427, 0.0015, 0.0285)

names(er) <- asset.names
covmat <- matrix(c(0.0100, 0.0018, 0.0011,0.0018, 0.0109, 0.0026,0.0011, 0.0026, 0.0199),nrow=3, ncol=3)

rk.free <- 0.005

dimnames(covmat)<- list(asset.names, asset.names)
ew = rep(1,3)/3

equalWeight.portfolio = getPortfolio(er=er,cov.mat=covmat,weights=ew)

print(equalWeight.portfolio)
```

### the output will be

```
Call:
getPortfolio(er = er, cov.mat = covmat, weights = ew)

Portfolio expected return:     0.02423333 
Portfolio standard deviation:  0.07586538 
Portfolio weights:
MSFT   NORD   SBUX 
0.3333 0.3333 0.3333
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different methodology, but I think it will give you what you want.

```
library(stockPortfolio) # Base package for retrieving returns
library(ggplot2) # Used to graph efficient frontier
library(reshape2) # Used to melt the data
library(quadprog) #Needed for solve.QP

# Create the portfolio using ETFs, incl. hypothetical non-efficient allocation
stocks <- c(
 "VTSMX" = .0,
 "SPY" = .20,
 "EFA" = .10,
 "IWM" = .10,
 "VWO" = .30,
 "LQD" = .20,
 "HYG" = .10)

# Retrieve returns, from earliest start date possible (where all stocks have
# data) through most recent date
returns <- getReturns(names(stocks[-1]), freq="week") #Currently, drop index

#### Efficient Frontier function ####
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="no", max.allocation=NULL,
 risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.005){
 # return argument should be a m x n matrix with one column per security
 # short argument is whether short-selling is allowed; default is no (short
 # selling prohibited)max.allocation is the maximum % allowed for any one
 # security (reduces concentration) risk.premium.up is the upper limit of the
 # risk premium modeled (see for loop below) and risk.increment is the
 # increment (by) value used in the for loop

 covariance <- cov(returns)
 print(covariance)
 n <- ncol(covariance)

 # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint
 # (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
 Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
 bvec <- 1
 meq <- 1

 # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
 if(short=="no"){
 Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
 }

 # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
 if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
 if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
 stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
 }
 if(max.allocation * n < 1){
 stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
 }
 Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
 }

 # Calculate the number of loops
 loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
 loop <- 1

 # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
 # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
 eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
 # Now I need to give the matrix column names
 colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")

 # Loop through the quadratic program solver
 for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
 dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution along the EF
 sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
 eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution*colSums((covariance*sol$solution))))
 eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
 eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
 eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
 loop <- loop+1
 }

 return(as.data.frame(eff))
}

# Run the eff.frontier function based on no short and 50% alloc. restrictions
eff <- eff.frontier(returns=returns$R, short="no", max.allocation=.50,
 risk.premium.up=1, risk.increment=.001)

# Find the optimal portfolio
eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe==max(eff$sharpe),]

# graph efficient frontier
# Start with color scheme
ealred <- "#7D110C"
ealtan <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark <- "#423C30"

ggplot(eff, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, color=ealdark) +
 geom_point(data=eff.optimal.point, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return, label=sharpe),
 color=ealred, size=5) +
 annotate(geom="text", x=eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
 y=eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
 label=paste("Risk: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev*100, digits=3),"\nReturn: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return*100, digits=4),"%\nSharpe: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""),
 hjust=0, vjust=1.2) +
 ggtitle("Efficient Frontier\nand Optimal Portfolio") +
 labs(x="Risk (standard deviation of portfolio)", y="Return") +
 theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=eallighttan),
 text=element_text(color=ealdark),
 plot.title=element_text(size=24, color=ealred))
ggsave("Efficient Frontier.png")
```

Take a look at this link for additional info.

http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio